# How to iterate Class Object from an ArrayList iterator

Tags: java

```
public class EmpArray {

    private int id;
    private String name,address;

    EmpArray(int id, String name, String addr)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        address = addr;
    }
    int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Employee details are ---");
        System.out.println("Id - "+id);
        System.out.println("Name - "+name);
        System.out.println("Address - "+address);
    }
}
```

In the main(), I have created an ArrayList to store EmpArray Class Objects
My intention here, is to not store duplicate Id..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class EmpArrayList {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws NumberFormatException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name,address;
        int id;

        //Create ArrayList
        ArrayList<EmpArray> arl = new ArrayList<EmpArray>();

        //Attach iterator to ArraList to check if Id is already added!!
        Iterator it = arl.iterator();

        enter:
        {
            for(int i =0 ; i < 3; i++)
            {

                System.out.println("Enter Id:");
                id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                while(it.hasNext())
                {

                    EmpArray temp = (EmpArray) (it.next());

                    if(id == temp.getId())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Id already exists! Add another Id : ");
                        break enter;
                    }   
                }

                System.out.println("Enter Name:");
                name = br.readLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Address:");
                address = br.readLine();

                //Create an object of EmpArray Class
                EmpArray e = new EmpArray(id,name,address);
                //Add this EmpArray object to the ArrayList
                arl.add(e);
            }
        }
        //Now display all the elements stored in the ArrayList
        /*for(int i=0 ; i< 3; i++)
        {
            EmpArray ea = arl.get(i);
            ea.display();
        }*/

        //Get Id from the user and display only that employee's details
        System.out.println("Enter Id whose details are required? : ");
        int searchId = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        boolean isIdAvailable = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)

        {
            EmpArray ea = arl.get(i);
            if(searchId == ea.getId())
            {
                ea.display();
                isIdAvailable = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isIdAvailable)
            System.out.println("Employee details are not available");
    }
}
```

I get an exception when I try to enter the Id the second time. Exception is at 
it.next()
Exception is Concurrent Modification Exception
Can someone please help as to why I have this exception?

Comment: It's definition should help you understand why. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html `This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.`

Comment: While iterating you're adding an element in the list at `arl.add(e);`,, Iterator is designed to be fail-fast, so for any modification during iteration it'll throw exception.

Comment: You can use ListIterator which is fail-safe, if needed

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating over array list `ArrayList<EmpArray> arl` and after that you are changing it's state `arl.add(e);` modifying it by adding value into it that's why `ConcurrentModificationException` came. If possible use another array list to add modified content into it.

But, you have issue with duplicate contents why not you use `Set` and `Comparator` or `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own duplicate-safety mechanism, consider implementing hashCode and .equals() in your custom object. This way you can comfortably use .contains on the ArrayList to avoid duplicates.

Here's a nice document about such implementation: http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that now you know why you are getting that exception, a simple way to do away with it is to not use the iterator, but use simple for loop instead.

```
// Attach iterator to ArraList to check if Id is already added!!
    // Iterator it = arl.iterator();

    enter: {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter Id:");
            id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            for (i = 0; i < arl.size(); i++) {

                EmpArray temp = (EmpArray) (arl.get(i));

                if (id == temp.getId()) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Id already exists! Add another Id : ");
                    break enter;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Enter Name:");
            name = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("Enter Address:");
            address = br.readLine();

            // Create an object of EmpArray Class
            EmpArray e = new EmpArray(id, name, address);
            // Add this EmpArray object to the ArrayList
            arl.add(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your inputs!
I now understand why I had such an exception.

I also understand that Sets are in place to avoid duplicates but my intention was to use an ArrayList and handle duplicates in it!
I am now not using an iterator but a simple loop!

Thank you again.